# Sketch: Vector does not preserve color and transparency when exporting as SVG

Tags: vector, svg, sketch-app

When I export as SVG from Sketch, the transparency and colors do not appear as intended.

What is going on here? SVG is on Sketch homepage.

[image: Original]

[image: After]

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say. Sketch usually handles SVG export phenomenally, and transparency should not be a problem.

Are you using blend modes in Sketch? Blend modes can sometimes cause problems, and even though the SVG format supports blend modes using filters they are not always supported by all SVG viewers.